# Using split method to split a string

Tags: java, split

1. The user is able to specify where the .txt file they want to import is located, via typing the location in via an onscreen prompt (this is stored within String 'importFile', which is being populated using a keyboard scanner).
2. Content of the file is then scanned using the scanner 'fileReader'.

   ```
   String importFile = "";     
   File Fileobject = new File(importFile);
   Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(Fileobject);

   while(fileReader.hasNext()) 
   {
     importFile = fileReader.next();
     String [] splitText = importFile.split("[-\\s]");
     System.out.println(splitText[0]);
   }
   ```

However, i am having some trouble then splitting the data within the text file properly...

Each line of text within the text file is formatted as follows:

```
abcd - efgh - 12.34 - ijkl - mnop
```

the text should be formatted as such after being split:

```
abcd
efgh
12.34
ijkl
mnop
```

i want the text to be stored within the array 'splitText' once it is split, so for example "abcd" will be located within splitText[0] etc. etc. though the whole string is being put into splitText[0] even after being split - screenshot follows ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYUjT.png)

Comment: I suspect that the splitting is working fine, but that the manner in which you output the result (which you do not present) makes you think otherwise.  If you want a more confident analysis then present a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnBollinger Hi. Yeah. Currently i am using "System.out.println([what i want to print])", so on and so forth. I've found that it seems to be grouping all first string into splitText[0] as opposed to splitting the whole string into splitText[0]...[1] etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is multifold:

1. By using `Scanner.next()`, you are reading the file one whitespace-delimited *field* at a time, whereas you want to read line by line.  Fix this by using `Scanner.nextLine()` instead.
2. As @YCF_L observed first, the delimiter regex you are using is unsuited to your particular task.  There are many variations you could use, but YCF_L's is clear and to the point: `"\\s*-\\s*"`.
3. After splitting the input, you print only the first of the resulting fields.  Presumably you did this to offset issue (1).

Putting those together, a read loop that does the job you want might look more like this:

```
    while(fileReader.hasNext()) {
        String line = fileReader.nextLine();
        String[] splitText = line.split("\\s*-\\s*");

        for (String field : splitText) {
            System.out.println(field);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, so this does get it printing out as i wanted :) - perfect! However, if i wanted to print out for example the values contained within "splitText[0]" the output is now the first part of the string, followed by the second part of the string three times. So it looks something like: abcdefghefghefgh, but ofcourse if it were printed out line by line. Only thing i want in splitText[0] is abcd, not the rest of what follows :)

Comment: @dstlny, my tests and a straightforward reading of my code disagree with your followup claim.  In the code presented in this answer, with the example input presented in your question, `splitText[0]` will receive the value `"abcd"`, `splitText[1]` the value `"efgh"`, *etc*..  Indeed, the fact that the output is correct shows this to be true.

Comment: i ended taking the loop out, and instead just printing the entirety of splitText[0] etc. into a table with a format which i setup beforehand. I found that each of the first parts of the string all got bunched into splitText[0], all second parts into splitText[1] etc. so this: (https://imgur.com/a/JcPi7) worked for my needs. And the output of the all of these in the console look like:(https://imgur.com/a/uWeGI). @JohnBollinger

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[-\s]`, you can split with `\s*-\s*` like this :

```
String [] splitText = importFile.split("\\s*-\\s*");
String result = String.join("\n", splitText);//Join the results
System.out.println(result);
```

Or to just print the results you can use (It work if you are using Java 8):

```
Stream.of(importFile.split("\\s*-\\s*")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Outputs

```
abcd
efgh
12.34
ijkl
mnop
```

---

[ideone demo](https://ideone.com/lf27jS)

Comment: This answer seems to imply that the problem is with the OP's delimiter regex, but I don't see it, and that's anyway not consistent with the output the OP reports.  The key difference between yours and theirs is probably in the part that neither of you presents: the bit that produces the output.

Comment: edited. Included the part which is producing the output.

Comment: i thought the problem was in the regular expression @JohnBollinger i already edit my answer if that what you mean?

Comment: You are right that the regex is a problem, but it is not the *only* problem, and I would not rate it the primary one.